# Is it necessary to fetch an item via a service/provider when the item has already being passed in via navParams

Tags: angular, ionic2

Am looking at this [sample Ionic2 app](http://coenraets.org/apps/ionic2-realty/) and wondering why in the `broker-details.js`, the author has made use of the `brokerService` (line 20) to fetch a 'broker' when it has already been passed in from the 'broker list' page (line 16).

Is there a benefit to doing something like this? Is it necessary? Only reason I could think of, is in case data has changed between viewing the 'list' page and the 'detail' page.

broker-details.js:

```
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {BrokerService} from '../../services/broker-service';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/broker-details/broker-details.html'
})
export class BrokerDetailsPage {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController], [NavParams], [BrokerService]];
    }

    constructor(nav, navParams, brokerService) {
        this.brokerService = brokerService;
        this.broker = navParams.get('broker');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.brokerService.findById(this.broker.id).subscribe(
            broker => this.broker = broker
        );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You're not crazy or missing something. The code in the `ngOnInit()` function is redundant and unnecessary if the broker info has already been passed in via the `NavParams`.